# Passing params to children components in Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a template:

```
<template id="item-list">
  <form action="" data-bind="submit: addItem">
    <input type="text" name="addItem" data-bind="value: newItem">
    <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="item-list" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <item params="title: title,
                  $element: $element,
                  $data: $data,
                  $parent: $parent"></item>
  </ul>
</template>
<template id="item">
  <li class="item" data-bind="text: title, click: $parent.removeItem"></li>
</template>
<item-list params="items: items"></item-list>
```

And a couple of components with some logic:

```
function Item(title) {
  this.title = title
}

ko.components.register('item-list', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(params.items)
    this.newItem = ko.observable('')
    this.addItem = function() {
      this.items.push(new Item(this.newItem()))
    }
    this.removeItem = function(a) {
      this.items.remove(a.$data)
    }.bind(this)
  },
  template: {element: 'item-list'}
})

ko.components.register('item', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    $.extend(this, params)
  },
  template: {element: 'item'}
})

function ViewModel() {
  this.items = [
    new Item('One'),
    new Item('Two'),
    new Item('Three')
  ]
}

var vm = new ViewModel()

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body)
```

Is there a way to pass the item directly in the `foreach` so I don't have to do this?

```
<ul class="item-list" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <item params="title: title,
                $element: $element,
                $data: $data,
                $parent: $parent"></item>
</ul>
```

But rather something like:

```
<item params="$context"></item>
```

I am new to Knockout. I am aware that I could pass an object to the view model and operate on that object, so instead of `this.title` I would have to do `this.object.title` or `this.$data.title` and I would still have to pass `$element` and `$parent` manually.

Is there any other way to automate this that I am missing?

Comment: In this simple case, why would you separate the components at all?

Comment: I am just playing with Knockout, this is a problem I came across, it is not necessarily real-world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `$context` as follows:

```
<item params="{ context: $context }"></item>
```

Then in component code:

```
viewModel: function(params) {
    var ctx = params.context;
    var itemData = ctx.$data;
    $.extend(this, itemData)
},
```

But, you don't seem to be making use of the context at all, you're only extending `this` with the passed `item` data. So, the following will do as well:

```
<item params="{ item: $data }"></item>

viewModel: function(params) {
    $.extend(this, params.item)
},
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kajms2wo/)