# Pass observable to component through component

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, observable

I have quite difficult structure so I need to pass observable variable from main View to component, which will pass it to another component.

As observable takes it data from ajax call, at start it is undefined in last component.

How to correctly pass it?

---

```
<component1 params="data: $component.data"></component1>
```

.ctor

```
constructor(params: any) {
   this.data = params.data;
}
```

.ctor

```
constructor(params: any) {
    this.data = params.data; // here it is undefined
 }
```

---

All variables in all components are declared as observables

---

Situation is like in this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bdu9h8t5/2/). How can I made to see changed text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your child component must be set up to accept parameters in its viewModel definition.

```
ko.components.register('myComponent', {
  viewModel: function(params){
      var self = this;

      self.myObservable = params.data;
      return this;
   }
   ...
```

Then, per this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351843/passing-params-to-children-components-in-knockout), you can pass the parameter in curly braces like:

```
<myComponent params="{ data: $data.myParameter}"></myComponent>
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/bdu9h8t5/)

Comment: "...set up to accept parameters in its viewModel definition" - this already exists... about second - seems like didn't help

Comment: Okay attached a sample fiddle

Comment: Okay. Can you check this sample - https://jsfiddle.net/bdu9h8t5/2/ What I need to do to see changed text? Should I subscribe to each parameter?

Comment: :( My fault. Thanks